# Prove: $P(A_1)+P(A_2)-P(A_1)+P(A_3)-P(A_2)+... = \lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n)$

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, functions

let $A_n$ be an increasing sequence of events, how can I show that:

$P(A_1)+(P(A_2)-P(A_1))+(P(A_3)-P(A_2))+(P(A_4)-P(A_3))+... = \lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n)$

I know that it does make perfect sense to claim this but I don't think this is formal solution, how can I prove such claim with clear steps?

Comment: This is false as written.  Did you mean this instead? $$P(A_1)+(P(A_2)-P(A_1))+(P(A_3)-P(A_2))+(P(A_4)-P(A_3))+\ldots = \lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)$$ (which is true almost by definition)

Comment: Isn't it just a telescoping sum?

Answer (score 1):

If $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$ then $P(A_n)\le P(A_{n+1})$. Assuming the probabilities are positive and since they are weakly increasing with the index, then you cannot prove this in a meaningful sense.

The partial sums change at each step up or down by by at least $P(A_1)>0$ so there is no limit.

As Brian Moehring, if you pair the terms into brackets like $(P(A_1)-0)+(P(A_2)-P(A_1))+(P(A_3)-P(A_2))+(P(A_4)-P(A_3))+\cdots$ then you do get a limit for the partial sums of the brackets: since the sum of the first $n$ brackets is $P(A_n)$ the sequence of partial sums is increasing and bounded above by $1$.  That limit can be written as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)$

Comment: 1) "Since the sum of the first  brackets is (), that limit can be written as lim→∞()" How is this related to the fact they are bounded by 1.

Comment: Your original sequence did not have brackets, and unless you have absolute convergence (which you do not here) you cannot insert them.  Compare $1+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+\cdots$ with $(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots$

Comment: 2) I think this wasn't too clear and it shouldn't be that direct to claim such thing...

Comment: Probabilities are constrained to be between $0$ and $1$ so $1$ is an upper bound.  An increasing sequence of real numbers with an upper bound has a least upper bound and that is its limit. So $1$ is useful to provide an upper bound

Comment: ok and can you improve what I mentioned in 2 so I can accept? still what you wrote now didn't answer 2. you just showed 1 is the limit...

Comment: I did not say $1$ is the limit, I said it was an upper bound on the bracketed sum and that meant there was a limit (which could be $1$ or something less)